# Flask SQLAlchemy with Flask Marshmallow dump and load with different "column names"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I get the following JSON as an input:

```
{
        "832.547.13 Temperatur 1": "1337",
        "832.547.23 Temperatur 2": "2323"
}
```

But I cant use these JSON-Datafields in my db.Model, so I make this:

```
class DataModel(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Temperatur_1 = db.Column("832.547.13 Temperatur 1", db.String, index=True, quote=True)
    Temperatur_2 = db.Column("832.547.23 Temperatur 2", db.String, index=True, quote=True)
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to `dump` and `load` data with `flask marshmallow` with the names like `832.547.13 Temperatur 1`?

If I want to write a new row at the moment, I have to pass my JSON this way:

```
{
        "Temperatur_1": "123123123",
        "Temperatur_2": "123123123"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed it this way:

```
class DataSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    Temperatur_1 = fields.String(required=True, data_key='832.547.13 Temperatur 1')
    Temperatur_2 = fields.String(required=True, data_key='832.547.23 Temperatur 2')

    class Meta:
        model = DataModel
```